# Sum of squares in range between two numbers

Tags: c, function, math, formula

I'm supposed to write a formula for the sum of squares using the given function and its parameters. I am allowed to add variables but I can't seem to get it right. The formula I came up with only computes the summation between the two numbers (not the sum of the squares).

```
int sumOfSquares(int nLowerBound,
                 int nUpperBound) {
    // your code here
    int nSum;
    nSum = ( (nUpperBound * (nUpperBound + 1)) - (nLowerBound * (nLowerBound - 1)) ) / 2;
    
    return nSum;
}
```

Comment: If you're not using a loop, can you clarify what formula are you using to calculate the sum?

Comment: @Aziz this formula worked for me in getting the summation of two numbers. 
  
/* Suppose nLowerBound is -2 and nUpperBound is 4.
    The function computes:
    -2 + -1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 7
    The function returns 7.
*/

int summation(int nLowerBound, int nUpperBound) {
    // your code here
    int nSum;
    nSum = ( (nUpperBound*(nUpperBound+1))-(nLowerBound*(nLowerBound-1)) ) /2;
    
    return nSum;
}

Comment: This formula only works for summing a sequence of integers. It does not work for summing the squares. The easiest way to sum the squares is to use a loop.

Comment: This is not a programming problem. This is a math problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to compute the sum is to use a loop:

```
int sumOfSquares(int nLowerBound,
                 int nUpperBound) {
    // Initially set the sum as zero
    int nSum = 0; 

    for (int i=nLowerBound; i<=nUpperBound; i++) {
        // for each number between the bounds, add its square to the sum
        nSum = nSum + i*i; 
    }
    
    return nSum;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer recommends a loop. But there is no need for a loop here.

There is a well-known formula for the sum of consecutive squares:

- [Wikipedia: Square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number);
- [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: A000330](https://oeis.org/A000330).

The formula is:

```
 0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 == n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6.
```

This is from 0 to n. We can deduce a formula for the sum from a to b by subtracting the (sum from 0 to a-1) from the (sum from 0 to b).

```c
int sumOfSquares(int nLowerBound,
                 int nUpperBound) {
    /* sum of squares from nLowerBound**2 to nUpperBound**2, included */
    int lowerSum = (nLowerBound-1) * nLowerBound * (2*nLowerBound-1) / 6;
    int upperSum = nUpperBound * (nUpperBound+1) * (2*nUpperBound+1) / 6;
    
    return upperSum - lowerSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be like this:

```
int sumOfSquares(int nLowerBound,
             int nUpperBound) {

int nSum = 0; 

for (int i=nLowerBound; i<=nUpperBound; i++) {

    nSum = nSum + i*i; 
}

return nSum;
```

}